# What's the easiest way to sketch a directed graph?

Tags: graph, vertex, directed-graph

What's the easiest way to sketh a directed graph as shown here:

[image]

There are a lot of software which you can sketch graphs but I haven't found any with **edges with an arrow head in the middle** as shown in the figure above.

All the software I have tried such as inkscape, drawio, several office tools, etc. has only connector options with the arrow head at the end of the edge.